# Java Spring: Close socket session from server

Tags: java, spring, websocket, stomp

In my application, I have users connected to games using StompJS, and they have the option to leave. The server needs to unlink them from the database so this can't happen through the client. Then, I want to force the users to disconnect and close the stomp session.

I don't want to tell the client to disconnect because then the users can edit the Javascript and keep on listening to the game that they shouldn't have access to.

I only have a basic understanding of how these sessions actually work but I'm keeping track of sessionids with Subscribe and Disconnect event handlers. What do I need to do to disconnect users from the server? I tried to make a custom SubProtocolWebSocketHandler but I get an error that
`A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.`

There seems to be very little about this online so any direction is appreciated. Just remember that I don't understand this so well. Also please ask for clarification if you don't understand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not simply rely on the session timeout?

You can learn more here!
https://www.baeldung.com/servlet-session-timeout

You can also get the session and invalidate it when the time is right, and do everything you need as disconnect, etc. (session.invalidate();)

Comment: How can I get hold of the session?